# How to create an App Using Ionic Framework without including Ionic.js

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

We are currently considering building an app for iOS and Android using Angular Material.

Having worked with Ionic before, I really like the out-of-the-box dev tools it provides (easy Crosswalk integration, preview server, etc). Is it possible to still make use of those to build and deploy the project (as if we were working with a standard Ionic project), without actually including any Ionic JS or CSS components in the code itself?

Comment: http://www.ionicmaterial.com/ have a look at this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ionic ties in to Crosswalk through Cordova.
The Ionic CLI offers a lot of tools to make working with Cordova easier so it is worth keeping Ionic around even if you don't want the templates.

You can easily get the benefits of Ionic like Cordova and Livereload without the Ionic JS and CSS by installing an Ionic app like normal and just removing the CSS and JS requirements from your HTML.
You can then use Bootstrap, Foundation, or nothing at all.

Ionic as a CLI and framework offers a lot of power, but ultimately it just creates a static web app with plain old HTML, CSS, and JS. There's nothing magical about it.

Comment: So i can create a `phonegap` app (not `ionic` one) that use `ionic serve`? As long as i installed the `ionic CLI`?

Comment: `Ionic serve` pretty much just enables live reload and lets you run your app from a server so you can access all aspects of JS. It also runs Gulp, compiling your Sass, Coffeescript, etc. And you can use Ionic to test your app for mobile. Then when you're done, you can package your www folder up in phonegap.